# an elegant way to transfer current date time into ISO 8601 format

Tags: java, timezone, simpledateformat, iso8601, dataformat

i need a to transfer the current date time into ios8601 format, something like :

date and time in format: `01 Jan 2014 BST 12:00 PM`

eventually on my jsp , i wish to put the formated date in

```
<time datetime="{date and time in ISO8601}">{date and time in format: 01 Jan 2014 BST 12:00 PM}</time>
```

my current try out:

```
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("BST");
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm'Z'");
    df.setTimeZone(tz);
    String nowAsISO = df.format(new Date());
```

but the result doesnt look like what i expect to get......

Comment: Do you want ISO-8601 format or do you want `01 Jan 2014 BST 12:00 PM`? The two are not the same.

Comment: 01 Jan 2014 BST 12:00 PM ,,  this is the one i want.. plz provide some code example is possible, cheers

Comment: @seph That example is not even close to any of the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. None of the formats use a name-of-month, nor do they use 3 letter time zone codes. A date-time would be in a format like  `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS±HH:MM`, such as `2015-05-31T21:00:17+02:00` or `2015-05-31T19:00:17Z`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did this Java question get marked as a duplicate of a C# question? I don't see how the linked question does anything to help resolve this one, given that the answers only offer .NET library calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern will give you what you need:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy zzz HH:mm a");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
System.out.println(format.format(new Date()));
```

Prints:

`01 Sep 2014 BST 15:37 PM`

*Note: I've assumed you were looking for BST = British Summer Time, which should be expressed as above. If you wanted Bangladesh time, use `Asia/Dhaka` as the timezone designator. Also note that British Summer Time is not in effect on 1st January (as quoted in your example).*

Comment: cool thx :P i gonna try out